# How do I find overlapping regex in a string?

Tags: arrays, regex, string, perl

I have this string:

```
my $line = "MZEFSRGGRMEAZFE*MQZEFFMAEZF*"
```

I want to find every substring starting with `M` and ending with `*`, without `*` within them. this means that the above string would give me 4 elements in my final array.

```
@ORF= (MZEFSRGGRMEAZFE*,MEAZFE*, MQZEFFMAEZF*,MAEZF*)
```

A simple regex will not do since it does not find overlapping substrings. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You missed `MZEFSRGGRMEAZFE*MQZEFFMAEZF*` . Any attempts from your side?

Comment: @AvinashRaj no, the full string contains a `*` instide, so that's not part of the result.

Comment: @AvinashRaj simbabque is correct, that would not be part of the final array because there is a '*' in it. The code I used does not find overlapping substrings, which is my problem.

Comment: In the future, please add the code you have already written and that you are facing problems with. That makes it easier for us to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expression matching consumes the pattern as it matches - that's by design.

You can use a lookahead expression to avoid this happening [PerlMonks:
Using Look-ahead and Look-behind](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444)

So something like this will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $line = "MZEFSRGGRMEAZFE*MQZEFFMAEZF*";
my @matches = $line  =~ m/(?=(M[^*]+))/g;
print Dumper \@matches;
```

Which gives you:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'MZEFSRGGRMEAZFE',
          'MEAZFE',
          'MQZEFFMAEZF',
          'MAEZF'
        ];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a recursive approach instead of an advanced-feature regex to do that. The program below takes each match and reparses the match, but omitting the starting `M` so it won't match the whole thing again.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

my $line = "MZEFSRGGRMEAZFE*MQZEFFMAEZF*";
my @matches;

sub parse {
    my ( $string ) = @_;

    while ($string =~ m/(M[^*]+\*)/g ) {
        push @matches, $1;
        parse(substr $1, 1);
    }
}

parse($line);
p @matches;
```

Here's the output:

```
[
    [0] "MZEFSRGGRMEAZFE*",
    [1] "MEAZFE*",
    [2] "MQZEFFMAEZF*",
    [3] "MAEZF*"
]
```